# How make a paragraph to continue in next page in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, text-formatting

In Word 2010 when the last paragraph doesn't fit inside the page it goes to next page. How can I make the paragraph continue in the next page without pressing Enter somewhere inside the paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

right click on paragraph, select paragraph from context menu, in Line and page break tab uncheck Widow/Orphan Control.